# HKCU registry key

Tags: windows-registry

I am a new Windows developer and want to store some user-specific config information in the HKCU registry hive. I want to know how I could add this in such a way that the key doesn't get detected as malicious.

Is anyone aware of any aspects I should consider?

Comment: What do you mean to add it in such a way that the key doesn’t get detected as malicious? What is your concern? If you add a key that is not malicious then it shouldn’t be detected as malicious.

Comment: Adding subsections/keys into `HKCU/Software/YourApplicationName` is safe and is never be detected as malicious one. If detected, it can be a flaw of the software which you use as a detector...

Comment: @Appleoddity What makes a registry key malicious? I'm talking about configuration only for my application, for example a path to a file storage location, and other values. HKCU\Software\YourApplicationName is exactly where I want to put it. Is this OK?